# Delete from Plist is not working?

Tags: ios, plist

i have a plist and when a user write notes i save into that plist along with their id,each time when user opens that it will check whether this user id got any notes in plist and display it in uitableview .Also user can remove notes but when i tried to do the following process i got exceptions

1.in view didload  check whether user got any previous notes or not
2.check plist with user id
3.if a match retrieve  corresponding notes
4.and save it into a mutable array .so when user add a new note first we use the previous mutable array to store the new note and write it again to plist  //not working for me.
5.when user delete a notes then update itinto plist

Comment: ever considered that on a coding site, showing code would be better than a description of said code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a structure something similar to this

```
[
    {
        "UserID": 1,
        "Notes": [
            {
                "NoteID": 1,
                "Desc": "Description"
            },{
                "NoteID": 2,
                "Desc": "Description"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Plist File Path in documents directory

```
- (NSString *)userNotesFilePath{

   NSString *documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                              NSUserDomainMask,
                                                              YES)[0]; 

    return [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserNotes.plist"];

}
```

Method fetches saved notes for a user Id

```
- (NSArray *)savedNotesForUserID:(NSInteger)userID{

    NSString *filePath = [self userNotesFilePath];
    NSArray *savedNotes = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UserID = %d",userID];

    NSDictionary *user = [[savedNotes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]lastObject];

    return  user[@"Notes"];
}
```

Saves new notes array as such to a particular userID

```
- (void)insertNotes:(NSArray *)notesArray  forUserID:(NSUInteger)userID{

    if (!notesArray) {
        return;
    }

    NSString *filePath = [self userNotesFilePath];
    NSMutableArray *savedNotes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UserID = %d",userID];

    NSInteger index = [savedNotes indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        return [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
    }];

    NSMutableDictionary *user = [savedNotes[index] mutableCopy];
    user[@"Notes"] = notesArray;

    [savedNotes replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:user];
    [savedNotes writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Insert one note to saved notes

```
- (void)insertNote:(NSDictionary *)userNote  forUserID:(NSUInteger)userID{

    if (!userNote) {
        return;
    }

    NSString *filePath = [self userNotesFilePath];
    NSMutableArray *savedNotes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"UserID = %d",userID];

    NSInteger index = [savedNotes indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        return [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
    }];

    NSMutableDictionary *user = [savedNotes[index] mutableCopy];

    NSMutableArray *savedUserNotes = [user[@"Notes"] mutableCopy];
    if (!savedUserNotes) {
        savedUserNotes = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    [savedUserNotes addObject:userNote];

    user[@"Notes"] = savedUserNotes;

    [savedNotes replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:user];
    [savedNotes writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```